# How do I change the dimensions of the quciktime movie file

Tags: javascript, quicktime, panoramas

Here is the source code of my panoramic view file, when I tried to change the dimensions of this movie all it changes the position of movie in the page but it doesn't change the dimensions of the movie file.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload = "regListeners()">
    <script src="acquicktime.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    QT_WriteOBJECT_XHTML('WRTPANORAMICVIEW.mov', '1000', '1000', 'autoplay',                                                          
                          'true', 'loop', 'false', 'qtnext1')
    </script>
</body>
```

[image]
Here is the screen shot of the file after changing the dimensions

Comment: Could you put your code into a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)/[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/)? That way we can see your code and edit it ourselves.

Comment: okei... evolutionbox, i'll upload it over there for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try with '1000px'

```
QT_WriteOBJECT_XHTML('WRTPANORAMICVIEW.mov', '1200px', '900px', 'autoplay', 'true', 'loop', 'false', 'qtnext1')
```

or

```
QT_WriteOBJECT_XHTML('WRTPANORAMICVIEW.mov', '100%', '100%', 'autoplay', 'true', 'loop', 'false', 'qtnext1')
```

but even what you wrote should work.

Comment: Sorry wast, the same result.

Comment: do you have a live example?

Comment: Shall I share you the screen shot after editing as per your anwser?